# What are the android devices Supported by ARCore?

Tags: arcore

ARCore supports the following devices only

Google Pixel, Pixel XL, Pixel 2, Pixel 2 XL
Samsung Galaxy S8

Comment: Question is not clear...

Comment: Sorry. Except these what are the other devices are supports ARCore?

Answer (score 0):

Check out ARCoreForAll. You could also try installing the arcore apk provided by google onto a tablet to see if it works. I have had a significant amount of luck installing the official arcore apk on non-supported devices.